# Can an akka cluster be deployed on Heroku/Clever Cloud?

Tags: heroku, akka-cluster

My project consists of a web frontend which uses the Play! framework and a backend of distributed nodes in charge of doing the work, which were originally designed to run on different machines. I used akka-cluster as a means of communication between both sides of my system, and everything worked great locally, but when I got to deployment time I found out that Heroku/Clever Cloud apps can only talk to each other via HTTP, while akka-cluster communicates through TCP. I have searched the web and found older questions regarding the topic that say to use RabbitMQ, but, as I understand it, I would have to rewrite the communication between parties without using the clustering library and all of its goodness. So, my question is, is this the only way to solve my issue? The responses I read were from 2011, so I'm hoping something has been developed for this scenario.

Comment: You can bind your nodes to port 80, and pretend to talk via HTTP, if Heroku applies some restrictions to the port numbers of the services to be bound.

Comment: Thanks! But how would I go about it? Akka-cluster manages a great deal of messaging transparently, such as gossip protocols and addition and removal of nodes, so I wouldn't know how to wrap/unwrap all of the communications.

Comment: By default a node in the cluster listens on port 2551. Just configure the nodes to listen on port 80 instead.

Comment: I did, but it still didn't work. I think that the way they check if the application is running must be through a "Ping" of some sort through an http request to my port, which it doesn't understand. That could be it, or maybe I'm wrong about something.